# Serving Django application from relative path

Tags: django, apache, mod-wsgi, relative-path

I am developing a Django application which works fine locally.  In production, the application will be served from a relative path, such as `www.example.com/app/`.

I am using Apache with mod_wsgi, and I have configured Apache to serve the application from the relative URL:

```
WSGIScriptAlias /app /path/to/my/modwsgi.py
WSGIDaemonProcess app display-name=app_wsgi
```

Unfortunately, I get an Error 404. The debug information, though, is pretty mysterious. If I try to get `www.example.com/app/myurl/`, Django says

```
Using the URLconf defined in apps.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

    ^myurl/$
    ...

The current URL, myurl/, didn't match any of these.
```

It seems that Django - correctly - infers that the path requested is `myurl/`, and not `app/myurl/`. But, even though `myurl/` clearly matches `^myurl/$`, it does not find a match.

I have also tried to add the setting

```
FORCE_SCRIPT_NAME = '/app'
```

but nothing changes - the error message remains identical.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The debug information lies :-/ Trying with more permissive regexs in the URL conf; iwas able to get a page. From there I could print `request.path`, and it turned out to be `app/myurl/`.

To make it work, I had instead to put

```
FORCE_SCRIPT_NAME = ''
STATIC_URL = '/app/static/'
MEDIA_URL = '/app/media/'
```

Comment: You shouldn't need to do that, it should just work. Edit your original question and add the contents of your WSGI script file. You may have copied fixups meant for 0.96 of Django which would screw things up. BTW, are you using WSGIProcessGroup directive? If not, you have set up a daemon process and aren't using it. Go check official docs on mod_wsgi site and ensure you are following them and not some arbitrary persons blog post about it.